# porqué solo me actualiza el estado cuando obtiene el valor del EditText que escribí el numero del documento. y nó cuando le doy el textview que buscó

Tags: android, json

'ESTE ES EL METODO DEL ONCLICK solo actualiza cuando le doy el valor del texto que escribo en el edittext , pero cuando le doy un textview que muestra antes de cambiar el estado no agarra.'

```
private void webServiceActualizar() {
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.show();
       
        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/JSONActualizarEstados.php?
' ese campo obtiene el valor del edittext 'DOCUMENTO="+asiCampoDocumento.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se ha Actualizado el estado con exito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TxtAsiID.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TxtAsiNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TxtAsiTipo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TxtAsiDocumento.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TxtAsiRubro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Btn_cambiar_estado.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            asiCampoDocumento.setText("");
    
            stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    pDialog.hide();
    
                    if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("elimina")){
    
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se ha Eliminado con exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("noExiste")){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se encuentra la persona ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"actualizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                        }
    
                    }
    
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha podido conectar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            });
            request.add(stringRequest);
    
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, Cuál es el método onClick? Cuál es el EditText y cuál el textview al que te refieres?. No olvides revisar [ask] ,saludos.

Comment: El método onclick sólo ejecuta ese método. Sólo cuando le doy el gettext del número que escribo en el edittext actualiza el estado de la persona. Pero cuando doy consultar con el edittext. Devuelves 3 campos de la bd la cuál las muestra en textview pero quiero que actualice el estado agarrando el texto de unos de los textview pero no da efecto. Sólo da efecto cuando agarra el texto del edittext que escribí para la consulta.

Comment: Hola edukokas, al menos a mi, se me hace difícil entneder tu pregunta sin poder ver el html, podrías agregarlo?.